# Where do the bits/X (e.g bits/errno.h) header files come from?

Tags: c, linux, unix, header-files

I notice under my /usr/include directory, there is a folder called "bits" with a bunch of header files. Some of the files are "bits/errno.h" or "bits/in.h".

Where do these files come from? They don't look to be part of libc. E.g, musl doesn't ship with them: https://github.com/cloudius-systems/musl/tree/master/include, however, I do notice that musl does depend on them.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) may help.

Comment: They are provided by the compiler and/or libraries.  They're designed to provide bits of information that may be needed by one or more other headers.  They may vary between different types of system.  They limit the platform-specific changes for major headers.  They should not be used directly by a program — programs should include `"header.h"` or `"sys/header.h"` (or use the angle-bracket notation `<sys/header.h>`).  The preprocessor selects the correct `bits/*.h` files.

Answer (score 0):

They're most likely part of `libc(x)-dev` (nomenclature will depend on your distro of choice)...

For the debian/ubuntu family you could try

```
dpkg -S /path/to/bits/errno.h
```

For the RHEL/Centos family you could try

```
rpm -qf /path/to/bits/errno.h
```